# PhoneGap 2.2.0 Custom Build Configuration

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova

If I make a custom build configuration by duplicating the release build and name it 'release-test' I get the following errors when trying to run it:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issue : 'Cordova/CVViewController.h' file not found
Lexical or Preprocessor issue : 'Cordova/CVViewController.h' file not found
```

Switching back to the default staging and release build works fine.

Whats going on :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay I seemed to find a fix for this, I had to create the same build configuration with the same name in the CordovaLib project settings.